# Modificar los valores de una lista con base en los resultados de otra lista

Tags: python, condiciones, spyder

Estoy haciendo un código para practicar data science, y decidí hacer un código para detectar diabetes en un numero grande de personas.

Decidí generar características aleatorias para cada paciente (con random.randint) y crear una lista con el numero de paciente con sus valores iniciales siendo 0 llamada probabilidad[] y después, comparar cada una elemento para ver si es sano o no, ejemplo; sus niveles de glucosa.Finalmente, con base en si cumple esa comparación los requisitos necesarios, modificar mi lista probabilidad[], aumentando adecuadamente el valor inicial.

```
probabilidad = []

for s in embarazos:
    if s >= 1:
        probabilidad.append(1)
    else:
        probabilidad.append(0)

for n in glucosa:
    if n >= 80:
        probabilidad[n] == n+1
    elif n<= 130:
        probabilidad[n]== n+1
    else:
        probabilidad[n]= n+0
```

Por lo tanto, el resultado esperado es *Si los niveles de glucosa son menores a 80 o mayores a 130, el valor en el indice n dentro de probabilidad, incremente en 1*

Pero los valores en probabilidad[] No se ven afectados Alguna recomendacion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- **Primero:** no entiendo por que sumas n a la probabilidad, según
  lo que dices creo que lo que quieres hacer es sumar 1 a la
  probabilidad.
- **Segundo:** no estas recorriendo de forma adecuada la lista
  probabilidad. Date cuenta de que n puede valer 80, 130, 93, etc. Porque son los datos de la lista de glucosa, y por lo tanto no lo puedes usar como indice para la lista de probabilidad

Suponiendo que la lista de glucosa tiene el mismo tamaño que la lista de probabilidad, es decir, que glucosa[i] es el valor de la glucosa que tiene el paciente con probabilidad[i] de tener diabetes, haría el siguiente código:

```
i = 0
for n in glucosa:
    if n >= 80:
        probabilidad[i] += 1
    elif n<= 130:
        probabilidad[i] += 1
    i += 1
```